# RDLC split string with spaces and add color

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm having the below number format in my RDLC report

**BM13421090**

I need to add spaces and apply a color to the number. End result should be like below

**BM 13 4210 90**

and **Number 4210 need to be in red color**. Number will always have the same number of characters and spaces and the color will be added in the same way.

I'm trying to achieve it with the split function =Split(First(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value),",")(2).Unfortunately,cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with the following expression

```
=iif (IsNothing(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value),
"",mid(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value,1,2)+" "+
mid(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value,3,2)+" "+
"<span style='color:red'>"+mid(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value,5,4)+"</span>"+" "+
mid(Fields!StudentRegistrationNo.Value,9,4))
```